# Error calling member function "FETCH_ASSOC" - what is wrong with my code?

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to connect to a PHP PDO and run a simple query on the data but I run into an error about the object not being created? I'm trying to make this as simple as possible and have been advised not to make a singleton database class and instead define the Database PDO whenever I need it, which is for this initial (simple) query.

Here is the error I am getting. What do I need to do to fix the code?

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in/home/...index.php on line 11

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "x";
$dbuser = "y";
$dbpass = "z";

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;db_name=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tablename");

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['field_name'],'<br>';
}
?>
```

And please let me know if you have a better way to select data from a mysql table using php. Trying to learn PDO and not mysqli. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose between `->query` or `->fetch`. You can't mix both *method*.

[`->query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php):

```
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tablename';
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo $row['field_name'],'<br>';
    }
```

[`->fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename");
$sth->execute();

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['field_name'],'<br>';
}
```

Comment: I think it is also possible to get the PDOStatement from query() (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) and then call fetch() (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) on it.

Comment: Thanks. What is wrong with "PDO::FETCH_ASSOC" ? Why must I used PDO::FETCH_NUM and FETCH_ORI_NEXT instead of "PDO::FETCH_ASSOC" ?

Comment: Num will return an array with numeric key when assoc will return an array with column name as key. It's just an example. You can of course use assoc.

Comment: @j0k I want to use the fetch->() method as it makes use of a PDO Statement (which is what I am trying to learn) however I don't understand in your "while loop" you have used $stmt ? Shouldn't it be $sth? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a problem with the query, like a typo or the table does not exist.

Then `$query` is not a [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) but `false` and you can't call `false->fetch()`.

Comment: Can I make $query a PDOStatement and if so, how?

Comment: Issue a correct SQL query. :) Try `var_dump($db->errorInfo());` after the query() call.

Answer (score 1):

There's your typo:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;db_name=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

Should be:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

After fixing the typo this code works perfectly:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM wp_blogs");

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row).'<br>';
}
```

Comment: good eye! this was a syntax error but I still had same error... :/ it was the fact that $query is not a PDOStatement ... I have to use fetch.